# Why does my view update when I have an alert in my function but doesn't when I do not

Tags: javascript, html, partial-page-refresh

so i have an html page call index.html, it looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<title>sometitle</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />  

</head>
<body>
<div id="Screen">
<section class="loginform cf">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="loginwindow">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="usermail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="useremail" placeholder="youremail@email.com" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for"password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Check In">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</section>  

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and it has a js file named index.js that looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginwindow');  
if ( loginwindow ) {
    loginwindow.onsubmit = function () {
        var useremail = document.getElementById('useremail');
        var password = document.getElementById('password');

        // Make sure javascript found the nodes:
        if (!useremail || !password ) {     
            load("LoopIt_DashBoard.html");
            return "success";
        }

    }
}
}

function load(url)
{

$("#Screen").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
}
});
test();

}

function test()
{

alert("test");

}
function test(string)
{

alert(string);

}
```

and a second html file called LoopIt_DashBoard.html that looks like this:

```
<div id="Screen">
<section  class="loginform cf">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="loginwindow">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Check In">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</section>  
</div>
```

now what this code does is get a email and a password and it compares the two. if they are equal then it changes the html in the div with the id Screen with the code in the LoopIt_DashBoard.html file. however if I take out the line which simply calls an alert (I use it for testing)

```
test();
```

from

```
function load(url)
{

$("#Screen").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
}
});
test();

}
```

then this function doesn't work, the page doesn't change. how do I get my view to update without using the alert.

Comment: Try using return true or return false (according to your requirement) instead of test()

Comment: Maybe unrelated but in your onload you set loginForm but then test loginwindow.  Also, the two definitions of "test" don't work the way I suspect you want them to.  The second redefines the first (writes over it).

Answer (score 1):

`alert` will pause the execution of the JavaScript function, allowing any other JavaScript triggered by event handling to take over, causing the context of the current event handler to be lost.

Without the alert, your `load()` will be forgotten, since your `onsubmit` event handler is going to return normally, and allow the form data to be posted, essentially refreshing the page, despite the action being `"#"`, because it's a POST.  So your view is probably updating, however, the document is also reloading, so it looks like it is not.

You need to cancel the `onsubmit()` of your form if you're handling it yourself.  One way would be to return `false` instead of `"success"`.

Comment: Great Catch didn't notice the missing `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the original Code it should not work, because you just set the Name Attribute:

HTML

```
...

<input type="email" name="useremail" placeholder="youremail@email.com" required>

...
```

Javascript

```
...
var useremail = document.getElementById('useremail'); //but you just set the Name Attribute
...
```

Except some unclean Code, it seems fine.

I would also Cleanup the code a little, for example:

```
window.onload = function () {
var loginForm = $('#loginwindow')[0];  
if ( loginwindow ) {
    loginwindow.onsubmit = function () {
        var useremail = $('#useremail')[0];
        var password = $('password')[0];
        // Make sure javascript found the nodes:
        if ( useremail && password ) {     
            load("LoopIt_DashBoard.html");
            return "success";
        }

     }
   }
}

...
```

**Important**
These Functions override each other, because of they have same Name

```
function test()
{
    alert("test");
}

function test(string)
{
    alert(string);
}
```

**TIP** if this is not the original Code, check/count braches curly and normal. That could explain the strange phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that javascript doesn't have overrides shortly after posting this, this is my first real attempt at html and java script.

Answer (score 0):

You are making typo too...

It should be be loginFrom in your if statement not the loginWindow.

```
var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginwindow');  
      if ( loginForm )
```